# Re-stream a live video from iphone to a server

Tags: ios, xcode, streaming, dji-sdk

I am getting a video feed in my app from a drone. The drone's SDK is giving me the video as `Data` or `NSData` into my app. I want to stream the same or divert the same to a server (for example a Wowza server). These two things should process simultanously.

Comment: Suggest me some good streaming sdk and i think i need to decode this data to a video format so that i can re-live it. I am getting video feed as data form drone inside a delegate function. Which is continously giving me data.

Comment: @ Sußh Choudhary, Did you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg library for restreaming it.
There is a sample ffmpeg swift or objective c

Comment: Can u please explain me how to stream video from drone to server a more explanation. Please

Comment: what's drone camera output? mjpeg , h264 ,mpeg2? 
you can stream any raw data or something with gstreamer or ffmpeg. 
first you need to reach the video data, then you can use it as a pipeline etc to restream anywhere you want

Comment: I am using DJI http://developer.dji.com/  according to it, it transfer some binary data and we have options in ios to save it in any format. When ever some data is recieved from drone we are transfering it using socket io to node Js and using i want to play the live streaming. But the binary data is not decodable as it is also not getting converted into video format. I tried it to play using vlc also(just drag and drop). I tried it converting to h264 format also it didn't played. I dont know how i can stream it. Any suggestion

Comment: According to me dji has a default encoding format of h264. but i tried converting binary data to h264 using ffmpeg its not working codec information is missing. Can u suggest me something or help me out in this

Comment: Can you directly get the h264 output ? You can try this,
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy  like that, 

this will give all aviable devices.
Then you can get the device output via 
ffmpeg -i video="THE_NAME_OF_DEVICE_LIST"  -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://....

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to send the video to a streaming service like YouTube for a year. The video coming into the iPad from the controller (connected to a Phantom 3 Advanced) is in H.263 format. ffmpeg is best at bulk transcoding, not a stream environment. Tried https://github.com/LaiFengiOS/LFLiveKit but it has bugs. It's a wrapper on ffmpeg that knows how to do RTMP.

The DJI go app knows how to do this, I've asked in the forum for help or code sample but they won't help. Bottom line is I can find no way to stream the video from the drone to a streaming service like YouTube or Wowza. I wish Wowza could accept H.263 native, but they site list only H.264.

So I can't give you an answer, but I can give you what I've figured out over the last year.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?